# Spinors in dimension 6

Tags: spin-geometry, spinor

From the representation of $\operatorname{Spin}(6)\cong \operatorname{SU}(4)$, one can deduce that on a $6$-dimensional manifold we get the postive spinor bundle from the usual $4$-dimensional representation of $\operatorname{SU}(4)$ and we get the negative spinor bundle from the dual or adjoint representation of the usual representation (e.g., see [Representation of $SU(4)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4325285/611719)). So, $S_-\cong S_+^*$.

But I am having a hard time to decode it in practice, for example we can have the whole spinor bundle: $S\cong S_+\oplus S_+^*$ and we have a metric on $S_+$, and we can give a map $*:S_+\rightarrow S_+^*, \phi\mapsto \langle\hspace{1 ex}, \phi\rangle$. How do we get the Clifford multiplication $e_i\cdot *(\phi)$ in-terms of $e_i\cdot\phi$, notice that for the action of the volume form $dV,$ $S_+$ is the eigen-space of eigenvalue $i$ and $S_-\cong S_+^*$ is the eigen-space of eigenvalue $-i$. Also for a spin connection $A$ and a positive spinor $\phi$, how do we see $D_A(\phi)$ acting on another positive spinor? Any description solving the issues is most welcome.

Comment: Although they're focussed on $\mathsf D_4$ rather than $\mathsf D_3$, you might find [TWF 61](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week61.html), [TWF 90](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week90.html), and perhaps other TWF's interesting.